# Validating password protected ZIP files

Tags: java, zip, password-protection, zip4j

I'm packing `ZIP` files using [`Zip4j`](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/). Sometimes, the created `ZIP` file seems to be (uploaded) corrupted via `FTP` so I would like to validate it.

The code snippets from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085637/how-to-check-if-a-generated-zip-file-is-corrupted) don't work because they cause an exception on password protected archives by default since the default `Java` [`ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) doesn't support password protections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the usual hash validation?

1. Create your ZIP
2. Calculate its md5 (`DigestUtils` from commons-digest may be used)
3. Upload the ZIP
4. Upload the hash in a text file
5. On the receiving side, rehash it with md5 and compare with the received MD5